# Wordpress - SQL query on two custom fields issue

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, left-join, custom-fields

I've got this query so far:

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['s_property_region'])) {
    $sqlWHERE .= " AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'property_region' AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = '".$_SESSION['s_property_region']."'";
}
if(!empty($_SESSION['s_property_bedrooms'])) {
    $sqlWHERE .= " AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'property_bedrooms' AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = '".$_SESSION['s_property_bedrooms']."'";
}
$sql    =   "SELECT $wpdb->posts.ID
             FROM $wpdb->posts
             LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id)
             WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
             AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'property'
             ".$sqlWHERE."
             ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date DESC";
```

It works if I just search for one custom field but not the two together. I know why and its because the way the LEFT Join works. There isnt going to be a row where post_type can be two things at once.

after the join Im going to get a structure like this:

```
|   ID   |   meta_key          |   meta_value   |
|   1    |   property_region   |   East         |
|   1    |   property_bedrooms |   4            |
|   2    |   property_region   |   West         |
|   2    |   property_bedrooms |   2            |
```

is there a query that can turn the two tables into a structure like this:

```
|   ID   |   property_region   |   property_bedrooms   |
|   1    |   East              |   4                   |
|   2    |   West              |   2                   |
```

If the query can make the table look like above then my simple WHERE this=that AND this=that will work.

Any help on this matter is greatly appreciated

Thanks

Scott

EDIT: After some searching about I now put this code together: http://pastebin.com/5YYDLyeR It works and returns the structure I'm after but as soon as I try to do a WHERE on property_region and property_bedrooms I get: #1054 - Unknown column 'property_bedrooms' in 'where clause'

EDIT2: Ok I have taken PMV code and to be able to do my WHERE clause I've had to do a sub-query: http://pastebin.com/dvTgsU7S This code does what I want but are there any better ways of achieving this query? I presume performance will be an issue when I have 1000+ entries in the DB...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feed your entire query into something like this:

```
SELECT ID
,      MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'property_region' THEN meta_value END) AS property_region
,      MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'property_bedrooms' THEN meta_value END) AS property_bedrooms
FROM (your query)
GROUP BY ID
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'property_region' THEN meta_value END) = 'east'
AND    MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'property_bedrooms' THEN meta_value END) = 4
```

EDIT: The HAVING clause.  It's ugly, but I think it's what you're looking for.  You'll still have to build it in the php code, but I think it should give you what you want.

Comment: Your query gives me the same problems as the EDIT bit in my question. http://pastebin.com/r24ffig6 is the SQL I now have, its a lot tidier then what I have but still as soon as I try to do a WHERE clause on property_region or property_bedrooms I get an error saying #1054 - Unknown column 'property_bedrooms' in 'where clause'

Comment: I made an edit to the code, give it a shot, I think it should give you what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks PMV I did come to the HAVING solution from some other code I found and I am now using this solution. Got side tracked and forgot to update this post with the solution I had found. But you beat me to it anyway :P